# Exposing a logging interface from a library

Tags: c, logging, middleware

I spend most of my time writing software in C. Lately, I've been working on libraries that would be classified as middleware. They only need to exist to make two pieces of software communicate.

During development,  I find analyzing logs much quicker and easier way to track down and isolate bugs. Obviously, I hope that any production use of the library does not require frequent inspection of the logging output.

But the reality is some bugs only show up in production environments. A common cause of this might be an implementation on the opposite side of the library that is doing something that is a grey-area in terms of standards. So, there exists a need to be able to analyze logs from a production environment.

So what is the best practice for exposing logging from a middleware type API? Is there any literature on this topic?

I have two ideas in mind presently:

The first is to use a `#define` to control the presence of logging statements in my source code. In production environments, the library could be compiled twice. One shared object would be with logging statements enabled. The other would be optimized without the logging statements. By changing the library dynamically linked against at run time, logging could be enabled and disabled.

The `#define` approach would work but might be inflexible. Additionally, I am not very concerned about performance. I take the approach of implement first, optimize second.

My second approach is to stick with a UNIX style philosophy and just have a function on the library for enabling logging by passing in a file descriptor. This would enable the logging to be enabled or disabled at run time. If the file descriptor is set then logging is enabled. If not set, then no logging is done. Obviously, this has its own drawbacks. But it is a simple approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my considerations:

- Logging always must be there

Usually when customer hits a problem, the first thing you want is the logs.

- Logging messages should vary by level

You should add as many log statements in your code, as you find usefull (think ahead). However not all statements are usefull all the time. There should be a way to differentiate messages by problem level or namespaces, so you can quickly select what you need

- Logging should be configurable

If you have a high-capacity server system, logging everything can generate you megabytes of data every second. You should have the functionality how to control what is logged and what is not.

As an example, you can take a look at Android logging API for C (cutils component). It is a combination of functions + macros to enable you add logging statements into the code.

Which mechanism you choose for storing logs on disk is your choice, but it is beneficial to use the most common approach for your platform (/var/logs for Linux, logcat for Android, etc)